# If I work with a frameset, Do I have to include jquery on each frame?

Tags: jquery, frames, frameset

I am working on a web application that is very old. It uses frames and I found that each frame includes jQuery.

Is there is a way to include it just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to include jQuery in each iframe where it is needed, contained iframes do not inherit from their parent.

Comment: Thanks, I´m using frames not iframes but I guess It works the same way?

Comment: Yes, frames and iframes are more or less the same thing in this regard.